# How do I apply the same code to a set of files in a folder (R Code)

Tags: r

I've written some code which cleans my excel file:

```
df - read_excel("filepath", sheet="Master") 

df <- df[-c(1,2,3,4,5),] 

colnames(df) <- df[1, ]

df <- df[-1, ]
```

This does the trick but I want to apply this code to a series of excel files within a folder & for the code to output a set of new files.

This is where I've got to so far:

```
files <- list.files(path = "folder path")

lst1 <- lapply(files, function(x)
{temp <- read_excel(x, sheet = "Master")[-c(1,2,3,4,5),]
names(temp) <- temp[1, ]
temp[-1, ]
 })
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Post the code you have tried that did not work. How did it fail? Were there warnings or errors? What were those?

Comment: Can you specify the issue in your code

Comment: Your `lapply` code does everything your first code block does. It sounds like you want to write the results to more files. Could you please provide details on that step? Do you want to overwrite the old files, or save the results as new files? DO they need to be Excel files also? It looks like you're maybe using the `readxl` package... if you want Excel files I'd suggest the `writexl` package for simple writes. Have you looked at that? Do you have code that writes a single file as you want and just need help applying it to all files?

Comment: Thanks for your comment - Ideally I would have a new set of files, so I have my original files, code is applied to all files within a folder, a new set of files is then produced. The first set of code above just needs to be applied to all files within a folder.